# Run std::function getted by binary read

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, std-function

I'm developing a application and my idea is store "apps" in files, like executables. Now i have that:
AppWriter.c

```
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <functional>
struct PROGRAM
{
    std::vector<int> RandomStuff;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> Functions;
    std::function<void()> MAIN;
} CODED;
void RANDOMFUNC()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        CODED.RandomStuff.push_back(rand() % 254);
}
void LOGARRAY()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < CODED.RandomStuff.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "["<< i + 1 <<"]: "<< CODED.RandomStuff[i] << std::endl;
}
void PROGRAMMAIN()
{
    std::cout << "Hello i call random function!" << std::endl;
    CODED.Functions[0]();
    CODED.Functions[1]();
}
void main()
{
    CODED.MAIN = PROGRAMMAIN;
    CODED.Functions.push_back(RANDOMFUNC);
    CODED.Functions.push_back(LOGARRAY);
    std::cout << "Testing MAIN" << std::endl;
    CODED.MAIN();
    FILE *file = fopen("TEST_PROGRAM.TRI","wb+");
    fwrite(&CODED,sizeof(CODED),1,file);
    fclose(file);
    std::cout << "Program writted correctly!" << std::endl;
    _sleep(10000);
}
```

AppReader.c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <functional>
struct PROGRAM
{
    std::vector<int> RandomStuff;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> Functions;
    std::function<void()> MAIN;
} DUMPED;
void main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("TEST_PROGRAM.TRI","rb+");
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    int program_len = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    fread(&DUMPED,sizeof(PROGRAM),1,file);
    std::cout 
        << "Function array size: " << DUMPED.Functions.size() << std::endl
        << "Random Stuff Array size: " << DUMPED.RandomStuff.size() << std::endl;
    DUMPED.MAIN();
}
```

When i run AppReader the functions dont work(Maybe why std::function it's like void pointers?), but in arrays or if i add variables i can see with debugger the data are storaged correctly (for that i tryed the vector of functions), but whatever doesn't work throw's me error on functional file. ¿Any ideas how i can do that?

Comment: `std::function` is an abstraction that allows you to bind a *callable* object and invoke it later. Your approach is never going to work because you're not writing the actual contents of the *callable* that the `std::function` was bound to. And even if you did write the target to file, you'll have to devise a way to read it back, compile it on the fly, and execute it. The same applies to the `vector`s; to serialize one you need to write the contents of the elements being managed by the `vector`, not just the contents of the `vector` instance.

Comment: The `function<>` is not the code, it's just a pointer. You are only writing the pointer, not the code. Also, you are not writing the pointers properly, because there is no point in doing that, so the functionality is missing. Imagine you have an `int*` to a lot of numbers. (No, you don't know the length.) You are writing the pointer to a file and loading it again in another process. Now you are asking why you don't see your data. Don't get discouraged by the downvotes and the answers but know that what you are trying to do is a hard problem and probably over your head right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're storing information about functions that exist in one executable, then trying to run them in a separate executable.  Other than that, your code does work, but as DeadMG says, you shouldn't be storing complex types in a file.  Here's how I modified your code to prove that your code works if run within a single executable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <functional>
struct PROGRAM
{
  std::vector<int> RandomStuff;
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> Functions;
  std::function<void()> MAIN;
} CODED;
void RANDOMFUNC()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
     CODED.RandomStuff.push_back(rand() % 254);
}
void LOGARRAY()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < CODED.RandomStuff.size(); i++)
     std::cout << "["<< i + 1 <<"]: "<< CODED.RandomStuff[i] << std::endl;
}
void PROGRAMMAIN()
{
  std::cout << "Hello i call random function!" << std::endl;
  CODED.Functions[0]();
  CODED.Functions[1]();
}
int main()
{
  CODED.MAIN = PROGRAMMAIN;
  CODED.Functions.push_back(RANDOMFUNC);
  CODED.Functions.push_back(LOGARRAY);
  std::cout << "Testing MAIN" << std::endl;
  CODED.MAIN();
  FILE *file = fopen("TEST_PROGRAM.TRI","wb+");
  fwrite(&CODED,sizeof(CODED),1,file);
  fclose(file);
  std::cout << "Program writted correctly!" << std::endl;
  //      _sleep(10000);

  std::cout << "---------------------\n";

  file = fopen("TEST_PROGRAM.TRI","rb+");
  fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
  int program_len = ftell(file);
  rewind(file);
  fread(&CODED,sizeof(PROGRAM),1,file);
  std::cout
     << "Function array size: " << CODED.Functions.size() << std::endl
     << "Random Stuff Array size: " << CODED.RandomStuff.size() << std::endl;
  CODED.MAIN();
}
```

The problem is not that you're storing complex types via binary read/write, per se.  (Although that is a problem, it's not the cause of the problem you posted this question about.)  Your problem is that your data structures are storing information about the functions that exist in your 'writer' executable.  Those same functions don't even exist in your 'reader' executable, but even if they did, they likely wouldn't be at the same address.  Your data structures are storing, via std::function, pointers to the addresses where the functions exist in your 'writer' executable.  When you try to call these non-existent functions in your 'reader' executable, your code happily tries to call them but you get a segfault (or whatever error your OS gives) because that's not the start of a valid function in your 'reader' executable.

Now with regard to writing complex types (e.g. std::vector) directly to a file in binary format:  Doing so "works" in the sample code above only because the binary copies of the std::vectors have pointers that, once read back in, still point to valid data from the original std::vectors which you wrote out.  Note that you didn't write the std::vector's actual data, you only wrote their metadata, which probably includes things like the length of the vector, the amount of memory currently allocated for the vector, and a pointer to the vector's data.  When you read that back, the metadata is correct except for one thing:  Any pointers in it are pointing to addresses that were valid when you wrote the data, but which may not be valid now.  In the case of the sample code above, the pointers end up pointing to  the same (still valid) data from the original vectors.  But there's still a problem here:  You now have more than one std::vector that thinks they own that memory.  When one of them is deleted, it will delete the memory that the other vector expects to still exist.  And when the other vector is deleted, it will cause a double-delete.  That opens the door to all kinds of UB.  E.g. that memory could have been allocated for another purpose by that time, and now the 2nd delete will delete that other purpose's memory, or else the memory has NOT been allocated for another purpose and the 2nd delete may corrupt the heap.  To fix this, you'd have to serialize out the essence of each vector, rather than their binary representation, and when reading it back in, you'd have to reconstruct an equivalent copy, rather than simply reconstitute a copy from the binary image of the original.

Comment: I know in single file still works, but i want load "Programs" the better and dynamic way as possible

Comment: @ErniCA - Then you'll have to have the functions exist in both the reader & writer executables, and you'll have to make an array of std::functions in both executables that map to each other 1:1, and then your file will need to store the index of the functions rather than a std::function<> of them.  Or else you'll need to store the code itself, whether in binary form or something like LLVM IR as DeadMG mentions, and you'll have to load/compile that code into the 'reader' executable's memory, and make it executable, and then you can run it.  But it can't refer to any global/static data.

Answer (score 2):

This is never going to work. At all. Ever. std::function is a complex type. Binary reads and writes don't work for complex types. They never can. You would have to ask for functions in a pre-defined serializable format, like LLVM IR.